# How to disable xkcd in a matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

You turn on xkcd style by:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.xkcd()
```

But how to disable it?

I try:

```
self.fig.clf()
```

But it won't work.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see this in the doc, does it help?

```
with plt.xkcd():
    # This figure will be in XKCD-style
    fig1 = plt.figure()
    # ...

# This figure will be in regular style
fig2 = plt.figure()
```

If not, you can look at `matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd`'s code and see how they generate the context manager that allows reversing the config

Answer (score 42):

In a nutshell, either use the context manager as @Valentin mentioned, or call `plt.rcdefaults()` afterwards.

What's happening is that the `rc` parameters are being changed by `plt.xkcd()` (which is basically how it works).

`plt.xkcd()` saves the current `rc` params returns a context manager (so that you can use a `with` statement) that resets them at the end.  If you didn't hold on to the context manager that `plt.xkcd()` returns, then you can't revert to the exact same `rc` params that you had before.

In other words, let's say you had done something like `plt.rc('lines', linewidth=2, color='r')` before calling `plt.xkcd()`.  If you didn't do `with plt.xkcd():` or `manager = plt.xkcd()`,  then the state of `rcParams` after calling `plt.rc` will be lost.

However, you can revert back to the default `rcParams` by calling `plt.rcdefaults()`.  You just won't retain any specific changes you made before calling `plt.xkcd()`.

Answer (score 8):

Just use that

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcdefaults()
# before showing the plot
```

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
manager = plt.xkcd()
# my xkcd plot here
mpl.rcParams.update(manager._rcparams)
```

this should reset the previous state, emulating the context manager.  Obviously, it has not all the features for a context manager, e.g., the reset in case of exceptions, etc.

Or, w/o messing with the internals of the context manager

```
saved_state = mpl.rcParams.copy()
mpl.xkcd()
# my xkcd plot here
mpl.rcParams.update(saved_state)
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to the beginning of your code

```
import matplotlib as mpl

mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `plt.rcdefaults` or `pyplot.rcdefaults` before plt.show().

it will surely reset the rcparams to defaults.
I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

simply use ,

`plt.xkcd(False)`

that worked good for me

Comment: consider adding helpful links to the documentation like [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html). It will make your answer stand out more. Also, avoid one-liners. They are poorly received.

Comment: Fonts don't get reset I noticed though squiggly lines go.