# Jupyter Notebooks prints a wavy, distorted graph with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization

**I tried a code-along tutorial for Matplotlib and typed up the following:**

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('ggplot')

ages_x = [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
          36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55]
py_dev_y = [20046, 17100, 20000, 24744, 30500, 37732, 41247, 45372, 48876, 53850, 57287, 63016, 65998, 70003, 70000, 71496, 75370, 83640, 84666,
            84392, 78254, 85000, 87038, 91991, 100000, 94796, 97962, 93302, 99240, 102736, 112285, 100771, 104708, 108423, 101407, 112542, 122870, 120000]
js_dev_y = [16446, 16791, 18942, 21780, 25704, 29000, 34372, 37810, 43515, 46823, 49293, 53437, 56373, 62375, 66674, 68745, 68746, 74583, 79000,
            78508, 79996, 80403, 83820, 88833, 91660, 87892, 96243, 90000, 99313, 91660, 102264, 100000, 100000, 91660, 99240, 108000, 105000, 104000]
dev_y = [17784, 16500, 18012, 20628, 25206, 30252, 34368, 38496, 42000, 46752, 49320, 53200, 56000, 62316, 64928, 67317, 68748, 73752, 77232,
         78000, 78508, 79536, 82488, 88935, 90000, 90056, 95000, 90000, 91633, 91660, 98150, 98964, 100000, 98988, 100000, 108923, 105000, 103117]

plt.plot(ages_x, py_dev_y, label='Python')
plt.plot(ages_x, js_dev_y, label='JavaScript')
plt.plot(ages_x, dev_y, color='#444444', linestyle='--', label='All Devs')
plt.xlabel('Ages')
plt.ylabel('Median Salary (USD)')
plt.title('Median Salary (USD) by Age')
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
# plt.savefig('plot.png')
# plt.show()
```

**The code prints a normal-looking graph on VS Code but prints a wavy, distorted graph on Jupyter Notebooks(Images Below)**

The problem is that the graph looks distorted and wavy in the Jupyter  Notebook despite looking fine on VS Code.

Graph from VS Code:
[image: ][1]]

Graph from Jupyter Notebook:
[image: ][2]]

Comment: Does some kind of style get applied in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you previously used `plt.xkcd()`, which basically changed `rc` parameters.
You can revert back with `plt.rcdefaults()`.
See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22287611/9214357) for more details.

Comment: :D for 15 min I thought "*no one seems to want to answer*", and when I finally post, here you are ;)

Answer (score 4):

it looks like you have used the [**xkcd** matplotlib style](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xkcd.html):

```py
with plt.xkcd():
    plt.plot(ages_x, py_dev_y, label='Python')
    plt.plot(ages_x, js_dev_y, label='JavaScript')
    plt.plot(ages_x, dev_y, color='#444444', linestyle='--', label='All Devs')
    plt.xlabel('Ages')
    plt.ylabel('Median Salary (USD)')
    plt.title('Median Salary (USD) by Age')
    plt.legend()
    plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5,4)
    plt.tight_layout()
```

[image: example]

One way to avoid setting style elements globally is to use a `with` statement (like above). Otherwise you keep various styles (which seems to be your case since you also have a grid).

Try to reset the parameters:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams.update(mpl.rcParamsDefault)
```

Or restart your interpreter / notebook and run only your code.